# Как подключить PHP файл

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, разработка-игр

Всем привет! Пишу веб-шахматы по данному примеру https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCFGgqplbro&t=4143s дошел до работы с php файлом (это начинается на 1:23:25 на видео), где, как я понял, должно осуществляться размещение фигур и дальнейшее управление ими.

Вот то что JS

```js
var map;
var divSquare = '<div id="s$coord" class="square $color"></div>';
var divFigure = '<div id="f$coord" class="figure">$figure</div>';

$(function() {
    start();
});

function start() {
    map = new Array(64);
    addSquares();
    showFiguresPHP();
}

function setDraggable() {
    $('.figure').draggable();
}

function setDroppable() {
    $('.square').droppable({
        drop:   function (event, ui) {
                    var frCoord = ui.draggable.attr('id').substring(1);
                    var toCoord = this.id.substring(1);
                    moveFigure(frCoord, toCoord);
                }
    });
}

function moveFigure(frCoord, toCoord) {
    console.log('move from ' + frCoord + ' to ' + toCoord);
    figure = map[frCoord];
    showFigureAt(frCoord, '1');
    showFigureAt(toCoord, figure);
}

function addSquares() {
    console.log('addSquares');
    $('.board').html('');
    for (var coord=0; coord<64; coord++)
        $('.board').append(divSquare
            .replace('$coord', coord)
            .replace('$color',
                isBlackSquareAt(coord) ? 'black' : 'white'));
    setDroppable();
}

function showFigures(figures) {
    for (var coord=0; coord<64; coord++)
        showFigureAt(coord, figures.charAt(coord));
}

function showFigureAt(coord, figure) {
    map[coord] = figure;
    $('#s' + coord).html(divFigure
        .replace('$coord', coord)
        .replace('$figure', getChessSymbol(figure)));
    setDraggable();
}

function getChessSymbol(figure) {
    switch (figure) {
        case 'K': return '&#9812;';
        case 'Q': return '&#9813;';
        case 'R': return '&#9814;';
        case 'B': return '&#9815;';
        case 'N': return '&#9816;';
        case 'P': return '&#9817;';
        case 'k': return '&#9818;';
        case 'q': return '&#9819;';
        case 'r': return '&#9820;';
        case 'b': return '&#9821;';
        case 'n': return '&#9822;';
        case 'p': return '&#9823;';
        default : return '';
    }
}

function isBlackSquareAt(coord) {
    return (coord % 8 + Math.floor(coord / 8)) % 2;
}

function showFiguresPHP() {
    console.log('showFiguresPHP');
    $.get('chess.php?getFigures', showFigures);
}
```

Вот что на HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Chess</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chess.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="chess.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="board"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Это на CSS

```css
.board {
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    border: 20px solid #55cdef;
}
.square {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.black {
    background-color: #999;
}
.white {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.figure {
    font-size: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Вот что на PHP файле

rnbqkbnrpppppppp11111111111111111111111111111111PPPPPPPPRNBQKBNR

только этот набор символов.

Как я понимаю, с их помощью происходит размещение фигур на шахматной доске и далее, человек на видео показывает, что если допустим переместить в этом наборе символов символ, отвечающий за пешку  "p" то эта пешка на выводном окне браузера тоже должна переместиться, но у меня никакого перемещения не происходит, не могу понять почему, памагите.

Вот пример того, как это делается на видео:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает. Выделите, например, один символ `p`, правый клик - Вырезать и Вставить между единицами `1111p1111`. После обновления страницы Пешка переместится.

Answer (score 0):

смотри если у тебя на пхп хранится переменная с паттерном то подключить пхп файл в html можно только самим пхп, сделать это можно так:

```
<?
include 'название.php';
?>
<!doctype>
```

обязательно это код тебе нужно в самый верх размещать и еще есть такой момент, если у тебя файл html хранится не в корне, то лучше пропиши так:

```
<?
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/название.php';
?>
<!doctype>
```

и потом чтобы выгрузить переменную в любом месте копируешь данный код как тег:

```
<?$var?>
```

если я не прав пишите.